# input fecha laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, input, livewire

estos teniendo un problema con mi input fecha, no logro que se cargue con un valor determinado, ya sea cuando es un nuevo registro, no debe permitir fecha posterior a hoy, y cuando modifico dicho registo, no me trae (muestra) valor que trae de db, solo me muestra mascara de entrada (dd/mm/yyy), tanto la inserción como edición las hacce correctamente, asi tambien las validaciones de formulario, el único problemas es el input fecha, resumiendo, quiero que cuando presione nuevo, me aparezca una fecha predeterminada un día mas del último registro en mi tabla gasse (es un registro diario), y cuando edite, me muestre la fecha solo lectura.

```
           <div class="form-group col-span-6 sm:col-span-5">
                <x-jet-label for="fecha" value="{{ __('Fecha:') }}" />
                <x-jet-input id="fecha" type="date" class="mt-1 block w-full form-control shadow-none" wire:model.defer="gasse.fecha" />
                <x-jet-input-error for="gasse.fecha" class="mt-2" />        
            </div>
```

Mi Componente

```
use App\Models\Gasse;
use Carbon\Carbon;


class GasseCreate extends Component
{
 
    public $gasse;
    public $gasseId;
    public $action;
    public $button;
 
    protected function getRules(){   
        if( $this->action == "updateGasse"){
            $rules = [
                'gasse.fecha' => 'required|min:10|max:100|unique:gasses,fecha,'.$this->gasseId,
             ];
        }else{
            $rules = [
                'gasse.fecha' => 'required|min:10|max:10|unique:gasses,fecha',
             ];

        }
        return array_merge([
            'gasse.fecha' => 'required|before_or_equal:' .( Carbon::now()->subDays(1)),
            'gasse.pm10' =>  'required|integer|min:0|max:35000',
            'gasse.pm316' => 'required|integer|min:25000|max:35000',
            'gasse.a9300' => 'required|integer|min:28000|max:40000',
 
        ], $rules);

    }


    public function createGasse(){
        $this->resetErrorBag();
        $this->validate();    

        Gasse::create($this->gasse);

        $this->emit('saved');
        $this->reset('gasse');
        return redirect()->to('/gasse');
    }

    public function updateGasse() {
        $this->resetErrorBag();
        $this->validate();

        Gasse::query()
            ->where('id', $this->gasseId)           
            ->update([
                'area_id'=> $this->gasse->area_id,
                "fecha" => $this->gasse->fecha,
                "pm10" => $this->gasse->pm10,
                "pm316" => $this->gasse->pm316,
                "a9300" => $this->gasse->a9300,
                "estado" => 'Activo',
 
            ]);
         
        $this->emit('saved');
        $this->reset('gasse');
        return redirect()->to('/gasse');
 
    }

    public function mount ()
    {
        if (!$this->gasse && $this->gasseId) {
            $this->gasse = Gasse::find($this->gasseId);
        }

        $this->button = create_button($this->action, "Gasse");
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.gasse-create');
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Supongo que debes jugar con los atributos siguientes del campo input tipo date para conseguir lo que quieres: `value="2018-07-22" min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31"` (datos de ejemplo)

Comment: Ah.. estoy con laravel 8 y livewiere

Comment: ni idea como se pone eso en laravel y livewiere... lo que te he dicho es html puro, imagino que simplemente lo agregas alli con los valores que desees en cada caso y ya esta.

Comment: por lo visto no es sencillo no me ha funcionado nada de lo que he leido y visto, gracias

Comment: pues ya le vale al laravel ese, siempre reinventando la rueda! :-)   Aquí hablan del tema, no se si te servirá eso del $cast que dicen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65458191/how-to-make-the-date-reflect-on-jetstream-x-jet-input  (no tengo ni idea de laravel, lo siento)

Comment: Buen día, puedes agregar también el componente de livewire que tienes para tu formulario?

Comment: agregado @HeytalePazguato

Comment: Normalmente cuando tienes un componente livewire tienes una función render (Que indica la vista que va a cargar) y una función mount que indica que variables van a relacionarse de forma directa con el componente livewire, puedes mostrar eso? Tal vez te falte algo en mount() o en render()

Comment: @HeytalePazguato `     public function mount ()
    {
        if (!$this->gasse && $this->gasseId) {
            $this->gasse = Gasse::find($this->gasseId);
        }

        $this->button = create_button($this->action, "Gasse");
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.gasse-create');
    }
`

Comment: Es un poco dificil de responder porque no has puesto toda la información completa en tu pregunta pero mira: Si `$gasse` es el resultado de una consulta a tu BD `Gasse`, lo podrías poner directamente en render() de esta forma: `return view('livewire.gasse-create', ['gasse' => Gasse::find($this->gasseId),]);` pero no has puesto de donde viene `gasseID` pero supongo que es alguna variable pública. Si esto no funciona te recomiendo editar tu pregunta y poner todo lo que se relacione con tu vista y tu componente livewire para poder analizarlo.

Comment: gracias @HeytalePazguato , trate de editar la pregunta y poner todo mi componente, pero no me dejó.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato ahí me dejo subir complemento completo

Comment: Ok, como muestra en la documentación de [livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components) tienes dos formas de hacerlo, usando mount() o render() y veo que en ninguna de las dos estas utilizando `$gasse` por lo que no va a hacer la relación con tu `input`